# how to have a field that conditionally MUST be null?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

This isn't quite a "sometimes required" field, but a little different.

I need to have a field in a Mongoose document that, depending on other data in the document, must NEVER be populated.

Is there a way to define the schema such that if field `a` is populated, that field `b` MUST be null?

I would strongly prefer to NOT solve this with mongoose hooks...

Comment: You can use custom Validators.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using custom validators, this example is for mongoose version 5.x.

```
new Schema({
 a: {
  type: String
 },
 b: {
  type: String,
  default: null,
  validate: {
        validator: function (v) {
          if (this.a && v === null) {
            return true
          }
          return false
        },
        message: (props) => `${props.value} should be null!`
      }
 }
})
```